# Adding child block inside static block not working

Tags: magento-1.9

Adding block B inside block A as child block is not working for me. Block A is a static block in cms page.

A category page display mode is : Static block only > displays block A
The static block has `{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}`.

I am trying to call a child block inside this `contactForm`, which is not working.

xml layout:

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="amodule/customblock.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

template: contacts/form.phtml has this code inside

```
<?php echo $this->getChild('customblock')?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the work workaround I have initialized the block in the contact form itself like this which works:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('amodule/customblock', 'customblock', array('template' => 'amodule/customblock.phtml'))->toHtml();?>
```

might be helpful for you too

Answer (score 1):

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="block1" template="path/to/template.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="block2" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Now to call the:

**block1** =

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('block1'); ?>
```

**block2** =

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block2'); ?>
```

Comment: #Prince, you are completely wrong. Why would I create two new blocks which doesn't even do anything in contactForm block ?